# Javascript, Дана последовательность символов, букв некоторые из них могут быть словами. Задача найти !слово в котором первой буквой явлеетcя 'a'

Tags: javascript, массивы

Не получается решить задачку Даны натуральное число n, символы S1, S2, ..., Sn. Группы символов, разделённых пробелами (одним или несколькими) и не содержащим пробелов внутри себя будем называть словами.
а) найти какое-нибудь слово, начинающиеся с буквы "а".
вот мой пример

```
let n = 5; 
    let array = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        array.push(prompt());
    }
    

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i].length < 2){
            array.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }

    let element = 'a'

    let indexanswer

    let idx = array.indexOf(element);

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[idx][0] == element){
            indexanswer = idx; 

        }
        else if(array[idx][0] != element){
            while(idx != -1){
                idx = array.indexOf(element, idx + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    
    console.log(indexanswer);
```

то есть сначала я избавился от всех букв, оставил только слова. После стал искать вообще ли присутствует буква 'a' в словах. Потом стал проверять является ли она первой буквой в элементе. И возможно именно тут всё пошло наперекосяк, потому что в консоли пишет мол я не могу в проверке `if(array[idx][0] == element)` так писать.

Comment: `избавился от всех букв` Т.е. `"a"` не является словом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а зачем так сложно?

```
const text = " 234   abc ggad  a    5gs ";

// разбить строку на слова используя в качестве разделителя пробел
const words = text.split(" ");

// просмотреть все слова и найти слово, которое начинается с 'a'
res = ""
for (word of words) {
    // если слово начинается с 'a' - запомнить его и выйти из цикла
    if (word[0] == 'a') {
        res = word;
        break;
    }
}

console.log(res);
```

или покороче, используя функционал `Array`:

```
const text = " 234   abc ggad  a    5gs ";
const words = text.split(" ");

res = words.find(obj => obj[0] == 'a');

console.log(res);
```

или совсем коротенько

```
const res = text.split(" ").find(obj => obj[0] == 'a');
```

Comment: Наверное, лучше сплитить по регулярке с произвольным количеством пробелов, чтобы в массиве не оказывались элементы с пустыми строками.

Comment: И ещё можно использовать https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith по назначению)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, можно, но я подумал, что не критично, если в массиве будут элементы с пробелами

Comment: Ну, если маленький массив, то не критично. Если большой, будет эффективнее) И ещё — элементов с пробелами не будет, они все пойдут на разделители, будет много пустых строк)

Comment: @vsemozhebuty, если очень большой массив, то лучше тогда через while искать сначала " a", а потом " " или конец строки - тогда все решение займет 1 проход по строке, причем не обязательно до конца